# Latex: Get rid of white space below image label

Tags: floats, captions

I have a document with quite a number of figures, some of which have a longer figure caption (in particular some take multiple lines). The image shows such a case:

[image: the empty space I would like to get rid of.]

I would like the second and consecutive lines to be aligned with the 'F' from 'Figure', i.e. get rid of the white space below the figure label.

The gecko expample from the wikibook (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions) shows this. But they seem to do nothing special to achieve this. Maybe a different software version?

How can this be done?

Thanks

Soraltan

Comment: If you're using one of the standard classes, load the `caption` package, and use the directive `\captionsetup{format=plain}`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Bernard's suggestions solved it: I added `\captionsetup{format=plain}` in the preamble and that's it. Thanks!